# SpringBootTest annotation in test classes

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I had an error during my jUnit test after adding a second test class.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test
```

...so I added (classes=...) part to the SpringBootTest annotation, and tests run fine.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {mySecondJUnitClass.class})
public class mySecondJUnitClass{
```

What I didn't understand is, I didn't add that "classes" to my first test class, I only set @SpringBootTest annotation and worked fine.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class myFirstJUnitClass{
```

When and why do we need that "classes" definition? Why is not @SpringBootTest not enough?

Comment: Your test is probably not in a subpackage of the package of your main class. Post your project layout: where is the main class, where are the tests.

Comment: Yes! this is it. Thank you. When I set the subpackage name, it run without classes definition!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer (by the help of [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet)). My first test class was in the subpackage of the package of my main class and the second was not. So this was why it needed a classes definition.